# PHP regex for matching a number in two sentences

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a php script where I need to create a regex rule to match two types of strings ( string1 and string2 in below code) and the matched number needs to be in $matches[1] ( should not be matches[2] ).

```
<?php
$ticketNumber1 = $ticketNumber2 = '';
$string1 = "[Ticket ID: 309972] New Support Ticket Opened";
$string2 = "Ticket #: 656398";
$regex = "/Ticket #|ID: (\d+)/";
if(preg_match($regex, $string1, $matches))
{
        $ticketNumber1 = $matches[1];
}
if(preg_match($regex, $string2, $matches))
{
        $ticketNumber2 = $matches[1];
}
echo "TN1: $ticketNumber1\n";
echo "TN2: $ticketNumber2";
echo "\n";
?>
```

Can any one help me with this? What should be the regex to be used to get the result?

Kindly help.

Comment: Why **must** it be in `$matches[1]`?

Comment: This is a little confusing.  You want a rule to match 2 types of strings?  The string1 and 2 look a lot different.  Also what is the deal with the matched numbers?  Do you want only numbers captured in the regex?  Do you want things to be included from string 1 IN the regex to check string 2?  The wording makes this very confusing on what is actually the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to limit the scope of the operator OR by using a non-capturing group:

```
/Ticket (?:#|ID): (\d+)/
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/vC0dG5)

Comment: @Kladizkov, since you are new, make sure to mark as answered so after the 15 minutes are up.

Comment: @Glavić Yup! And you can report bugs and suggest features! The owner is quite cool :)